# Redrawing and custom shaped windows question

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, c#-2.0

I'm using C#2.0 and I want to create a facebook style tooltip window. I currently made it with 2 windows and transparent key. One for the triangle arrow pointer and one for the square. The whole picture looks like that:

[image]

I have problem with the redrawing (as shown in the picture).

Is there a way to use whole shaped window on that? (While I need to make it sizeable)
If no, is this the proper way to make that? Or I need to 'glue' the triangle to the rectangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to solve --

Using transparency: [Irregular shaped Windows Form (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176720/irregular-shaped-windows-form-c)

Or using Control.Region which is the actual shaping of the window.  Plenty of samples or:
[How do I make a genuinely transparent Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308667/how-do-i-make-a-genuinely-transparent-control)

```
protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSizeChanged(e);

    const int ArrowSize = 25;

    Point[] points = new[] {
        new Point(ArrowSize,    0),
        new Point(this.Width,   0),
        new Point(this.Width,   this.Height),
        new Point(ArrowSize,    this.Height),
        new Point(ArrowSize,    ArrowSize),
        new Point(0,            ArrowSize/2)
        // don't need - autocloses
        // ,new Point(ArrowSize,    0)
    };

    GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
    path.AddLines(points);
    this.Region = new Region(path);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but if I use region, the window won't be resizable, am I right?

Comment: Tooltips aren't generally user-resizable, but regardless you can handle it the same as with transparent - you just need to recreate/update the region in your OnSizeChanged (or whatever) handler.  Regions have the benefit of *actually* changing the window shape for mouse hit tests and the like.